# Why not mvn install provide dependencies for installed jar?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have used to build a library that I need to install in the local repo for use in other projects.

I've tried `mvn install` in the project `basedir`.

I've tried `maven-install-plugin`:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <groupId>somegroup</groupId>
      <artifactId>someartifact</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
      <file>${basedir}/target/someartifact.jar</file>
      <generatePom>true</generatePom>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>install-jar-lib</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>install-file</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

The jar is installed correctly, but when I add dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>somegroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>someartifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to another project it's listed without showing transited dependencies.

The problem arises when running project tests that fails with `NoClassDefFoundError` for transited dependencies.

How to fix that?

EDIT:

parent project pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>somegroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>parentartifact</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>thirdpartygroup</groupId>
                <artifactId>missingartifact</artifactId>
                <version>x.x.x</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>compile</defaultGoal>
        <sourceDirectory>
            ${project.basedir}/src/main/java
        </sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                    <debug>false</debug>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <finalName>parentartifact</finalName>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

child project pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>somegroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>someartifact</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>somegroup</groupId>
      <artifactId>parentartifact</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
        <defaultGoal>compile</defaultGoal>
        <directory>target</directory>
        <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                    <debug>false</debug>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: did you use a central repository like archiva or nexus?

Comment: no, I need it locally only

Comment: when you execute `mvn clean install` in your base project, did you found the jar in `your_maven_repo/somegroup/someartifact/1.0/`folder ?

Comment: yes, jar and pom files

Comment: What's the content of the pom in the local repo? Does it contain the dependencies?

Comment: @ChristophBöhme yes, it has dependencies, and looks like a copy of the project pom.

Comment: Okay, then the install process seems to work. How do you execute the tests? Do you call `mvn test`?

Comment: Where does `someartifact.jar` come from? Is it the result of the build/package of that maven project? What exactly went wrong when you just did `mvn install`. What exact dependency is missing and how did you add it to your pom.xml (please paste the xml)?

Comment: @ChristophBöhme No, I run tests from IntelliJ that doesn't have transited dependencies configured in the project dpendencies and I don't know why. For example other jars like `junit` I see the dependency `harmcrest`, not in my case.

Comment: @k5_ yes, it's a result of clean package install, then added to the dependency of another project pom.

Comment: Can you try to run the tests on command line with `mvn test`? Perhaps it's just Intellij that has not picked up the dependencies.

Comment: @RomanC so most likely the dependencies have the wrong scope. Did you add them with `<scope>test</scope>` or `<scope>provided</scope>`. Set the scope to `<scope>compile</scope>` and remove configuration for the maven install plugin. After that `mvn install` should work fine.

Comment: @ChristophBöhme I tried it looks strange but it can't find my tests even after compiling it from the test source folder. Something wrong with the generated pom? Why Idea is not looking for dependencies in the pom?

Comment: That's weird. Can you add the poms of both projects to your question? And can you run `mvn dependency:tree` on the project that includes your library? What does it print?

Comment: @ChristophBöhme When I ran `dependency:tree` it's the same like Idea showing a tree without transitive dependencies for included jar. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079877/why-not-mvn-install-provide-dependencies-for-installed-jar#comment81110314_47079877) example.

Comment: Thanks for adding your poms. I've replaced the 3rd party dependency with an existing one on Maven Central and than did a `mvn install` off the parent project and afterwards called `mvn dependency:tree` on the child project. This listed all dependencies including the transitive ones. However, if I add the maven-install-plugin section from your question and call `mvn install:install-file` on the parent project then the dependency tree of the child project does not list the transitive dependencies. Could it be that you are using a version of your lib that was installed via install-file?

Comment: You could also try to delete your local repository (or move it out of the way) and do a `mvn install` of your library again to make sure that there is no other version that could accidentally be used by the child program.

Comment: @ChristophBöhme I've tried`mvn install` and a child lib is showing dependency on parent lib but without transitive dependencies. I have also tried to generate sha1 for pom and jar but it didn't change.

Comment: @k5_ I've ran effective pom and all scopes implicitly added `compile`, others that was defined explicitly `provided` didn't change.

Comment: I found the problem was in some dependency in the child project that was installed as `mvn install:install-file`. This third party jar needed to install to the repository but it has no dependencies in generated pom and also missing maven metadata in jar file :-(. When I removed this dependency my parent project dependencies became unfolding and showing in the `dependency:tree`. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `install-file` goal is meant to install an external jar file into your local repository. It is not meant be used to install the artifacts produced by a project built with Maven. Such projects should be installed with the `install` goal of the maven-install-plugin. This goal automatically installs the project's pom -- which defines the dependencies -- alongside the artifact in the repository.

It also has the advantage that there is no need to configure the install-plugin in the pom. Its always part of the build. Simply invoking `mvn install` without any configuration of the maven-install-plugin in your pom should work.

Comment: it's exactly installs the artifact either with `install` or `install-file` goal, but dependencies that listed in the pom aren't available.